# Second Chern class $c_2$ of $SU(n)$ bundle over $S^4$ v.s. $\pi_3(SU(n))=\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, fiber-bundles, characteristic-classes, gauge-theory

Let us compare the four statements:

1. Consider the $SU(2)$ fiber over the $S^4$. Such that this $SU(2) = S^3$ fiber over $S^4$ gives a second Chern class $c_2$ on the $S^4$ with $c_2=1$.
2. Consider the $S^3$ fiber over $S^4$ as a Hopf fibration, so that
   we have a $S^7$ constructed out of $S^3 \hookrightarrow S^7 \to S^4$.
3. Consider the classification of the homotopy map between the $SU(2)=S^3$ and the target space as the $S^3$ boundary of the flat $\mathbb{R}^4$, as $\pi_3(S^3)=\mathbb{Z}$. To compare with the first two statements, we take the unit integer class 1 in $\pi_3(S^3)=\mathbb{Z}$. I think there is a correspondence of this map to the above two constructions.
4. Consider the homotopy class map between $M=S^4$ and $BSU(2)=\mathbf{HP}^\infty$, so that $[M, BSU(2)]=[S^4,\mathbf{HP}^\infty] = [S^4, K(\mathbb{Q},4)]= [S^4, K(\mathbb{Z},4)_{\mathbb{Q}}]$ (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternionic_projective_space)
   which is $H^4(S^4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ (?). To compare with the first three statements, we take the unit integer class 1 in $H^4(S^4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$. I think there is a correspondence of this map to the above two constructions.

**Question 1 ---** How to show or prove that the above four statements are the same or related constructions? Especially the first two statements?

---

**Question 2 ---** I think this statement can be generalized to the second Chern class $c_2$ of $SU(n)$ bundle over $S^4$ v.s. $\pi_3(SU(n))=\mathbb{Z}$. How does it go? Here is an attempt.

1. Consider the $SU(n)$ fiber over the $S^4$. Such that this $SU(n)$ fiber over $S^4$ gives a second Chern class $c_2$ on the $S^4$ with $c_2=1$.
2. Consider the $SU(n)$ fiber over $S^4$ as a Hopf fibration, so that
   we have a construction out of $SU(n) \hookrightarrow ??? \to S^4$.
3. Consider the classification of the homotopy map between the $SU(n)$ and the target space as the $S^3$ boundary of the flat $\mathbb{R}^4$, as $\pi_3(SU(n))=\mathbb{Z}$ for $n \geq 2$. To compare with the first two statements, we take the unit integer class 1 in $\pi_3(SU(n))=\mathbb{Z}$. I think there is a correspondence of this map to the above two constructions.
4. Consider the homotopy class map between $M=S^4$ and $BSU(n)$, so that $[M, BSU(n)]=[S^4, BSU(n)]=?$
   which may be related to $H^4(S^4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$ (?). To compare with the first three statements, we take the unit integer class 1 in $H^4(S^4,\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}$. I think there is a correspondence of this map to the above two constructions.

Comment: Note that its not $\mathbb{HP}^{\infty}$ which is a $K(\mathbb{Q}, 4)$, but rather its rationalisation $\mathbb{HP}^{\infty}_{\mathbb{Q}}$. As for your first set of questions, are you aware $SU(2)$-bundles on four-manifolds are classified by their second Chern class? If not, see [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/195592/21564). As for your second set of questions, the structure group of every $SU(n)$-bundle over a four-manifold can be reduced to $SU(2)$ - this follows from obstruction theory.

Comment: You can ask countably many of these questions!

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Would you be so kind to explain the reduction in a little bit more detail?

Comment: @J.H: A principal $SU(n)$-bundle $P \to X$ admits a reduction of structure group to $SU(2)$ if and only if the fiber bundle $P/SU(2) \to X$ with fiber $SU(n)/SU(2)$ has a section. The obstructions to a section of $P/SU(2) \to X$ lie in $H^k(X; \pi_{k-1}(SU(n)/SU(2)))$. Since $SU(n)/SU(2)$ is $4$-connected, if $\dim X \leq 5$, then every principal $SU(n)$-bundle over $X$ admits a reduction of structure group to $SU(2)$.